# Taking a value considering the most recently amended date

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following columns where I need to take the most updated ID considering the most recent date an amendment has been made. For instance, I have used NVL(Updated_Date, Date) as Date, but am unsure of how to now take the ID that corresponds. The Code column is the one that I use to link to a separate table.

```
+--------------------------------------------+
| ID  |  DATE    |   UPDATED_DATE |   CODE   |
+--------------------------------------------+
| 123 | 1/2/2019 |                |   987    |
| 456 | 1/1/2019 |    2/4/2019    |   654    |
| 789 | 1/1/2019 |                |   654    |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Ideally I would retrieve:

```
+----------------+
| ID  |   CODE   |
+----------------+
| 123 |   987    |
| 456 |   654    |
+----------------+
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use aggregation and `keep`:

```
select code,
       min(id) keep (dense_rank first_value order by updated_date desc nulls lat) as id
from t
group by code;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the first row for each `CODE` which has the latest `UPDATED_DATE` then you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, "DATE", UPDATED_DATE, CODE ) AS
SELECT 123, DATE '2019-02-01', NULL,              987 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 456, DATE '2019-01-01', DATE '2019-04-02', 654 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 789, DATE '2019-01-01', NULL,              654 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT ID, CODE
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER()
           OVER ( PARTITION BY code
                  ORDER BY UPDATED_DATE DESC NULLS LAST ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

**Output**:

> ```
>  ID | CODE
> --: | ---:
> 456 |  654
> 123 |  987
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f6c2efc3441fa186452a83699fc314d0)*

Comment: Thank you MT0 and Gordon, I am not too familiar with how to use partition in this instance. The dates and updated dates are honestly all scattered and arranging them may not be the solution as multiple dates exist per ID. What I did instead was create a With table where I pulled the max date per code and joined that into the the larger query. This solved the problem I was having. Also, thanks for the fiddle link!